# How to get primary boundary value from EML file

Tags: python, email, awk, sed, boundary

I'm trying to get primary boundary value from EML file using sed

`sed -n -e '/boundary=\"/,/\"/p; /\"/q' file.eml`

but what I'm getting is a whole line

`boundary="B06E1103658.1514636705/test-box.local"`

instead of a value only

`B06E1103658.1514636705/test-box.local`

What I have done wrong? `awk` solution is welcome as well (or Python).

Comment: Whats your input and desired output?

Comment: do you mean `sed 's/.*\(B.*[0-9]\).*/\1/'` to get ot get only B06E1103658.1514636705 ?

Comment: @heemayl OP updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably simpler with `grep` lookbehind

```
grep -oP '(?<=boundary=")[^/]+'
```

will give you `B06E1103658.1514636705`, whereas

```
grep -oP '(?<=boundary=")[^"]+'
```

gives `B06E1103658.1514636705/test-box.local`

not sure which one you want?

Comment: It will be good when that `grep` will return first boundary occurrence as `sed -n -e` does by adding `-m 1`  and `| head -1`